# node-zookeeper-client getData execute callback only once

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, apache-zookeeper

I'm using `node-zookeeper-client` on my node.js server.

When I try to watch a znode data with the `getData` method, it works fine for the first execution.

The problem is when I update the node (with `ZK-Web` user interface) - the watcher only invokes on the first time I update the data. If I update it again - it won't invoke.
The callback dosen't invoke at all (only on the first run, not even on first update).

The question is:

1. Why the watcher only invokes on first update?
2. Why the callback only invokes on the first run and not every time the data changes?

My code:

```
zkClient = zookeeper.createClient('zookeeper-server');
zkClient.connect();

zkClient.getData('/path/to/config',
                 (event) => console.log(event),
                 (error, data, stat) => myService.exec(data));
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you use my answer? Otherwise, please feel free to comment and I'll elaborate/discuss.

Answer (score 1):

1. A watch is a **one-time** trigger. Read more in the [ZooKeeper documentation about watches](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches).
2. That also answers your second question: It only triggers once.

So in any case you have to re-register the watch when it's triggered. Read the docs to get a deeper understanding of the guarantees you get from ZooKeeper when using watches. It might or might not be important for your use case.